# Ambiguous use of ... in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using swift with coredata. What I try to do is quite simple. I have a DataClass called Topic that has as attribute "name". When I assign the value of this attribute is says "Ambiguous use of 'name'".

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let name = columns[0] \\ This is a String value
let topic = Topic(context: context)
topic.name = name
```

I've seen similar issues years ago, but nothing that solves this. Any idea?

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is entirely due to the fact that you are accidentally using `\\ This is a String value` instead of `// This is a String value` for comments?

Comment: @Sam, no I just wrote it. I don't really have the comment in the code

Comment: So you have any property named name in the class which contains the lines of code you show ? (A way to know is doing self.name = "")

Comment: @Ptit Xav That doesn't seems to be the problem. I try typing self.name and it gives error. Also, it happens with any attribute I want to change, not just name

Comment: What is the definition of Topic ? Subclass is NSManagedObject ?

Comment: @Ptit Xav. Topic is a class of CoreData and subclass is NSManagedObject. Entering the class I see I get the error "Invalid redeclaration of Topic" when in the code I just have the imports for Foundation and CoreData and the definition of Topic. I created this class from createNSmanagedObject subclass and I have the codegen as class definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In case you have the same problem, I just had to follow the steps explained in the link:
https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2017/03/28/core-data-solving-ambiguous-type-redeclaration-of-type/
After the "Clean Build folder step" all the error disappear.